# Icons above bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to put some icons (facebook, instagram, youtube, whatsapp) above of navbar elements, like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/wp/">
        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/cropped-logo-1.png">         </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
        <ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="navbar-nav">
            <li id="menu-item-10" class="nav-item active"><a title="INICIO" class=" nav-link" href="#">INICIO</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-12" class="nav-item"><a title="NOSOTROS" class=" nav-link" href="#">NOSOTROS</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19  nav-item"><a title="BLOG" class=" nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-20  nav-item"><a title="CONTACTO" class=" nav-link" href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it, Since you want to make your icon-bar above navbar as fixed, we will have to remove the `fixed-top` class from the `navbar`, because then giving `position:fixed` to icon-bar would overlap with our navbar.

So wrap both navbar and icon-bar inside a wrapper div and make that div as `position: fixed` instead. Rest of the things are self-explanatory if you know basic css.

Here is a code snippet or a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tan007/4sad0n87/3/) in case you can't figure it out,

```css
#top-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 999;
}
#top-wrapper .icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#top-wrapper .icon-bar ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 0;
}
#top-wrapper .icon-bar ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
}
#top-wrapper .icon-bar ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
#top-wrapper ul li i {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.section {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- font awesome cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="top-wrapper"> <!-- this is our wrapper div -->
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/wp/">
      <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/cropped-logo-1.png"> </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
      <ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="navbar-nav">
        <li id="menu-item-10" class="nav-item active"><a title="INICIO" class=" nav-link" href="#">INICIO</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-12" class="nav-item"><a title="NOSOTROS" class=" nav-link" href="#">NOSOTROS</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19  nav-item"><a title="BLOG" class=" nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-20  nav-item"><a title="CONTACTO" class=" nav-link" href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="section">Hello world</div>
<div class="section">Hello world</div>
<div class="section">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to load Font Awesome then use it.
Look at this links to understand how it works. It is simple.

[Introduction Font Awesome](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_intro.asp)

[Brand icons](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_icons_brands.asp)

[Instagram Example](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?icon=fab_fa-instagram&unicon=f16d)

Try this code.

Be sure that you loaded Font Awesome correctly.

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom">

  <div class="social">  

    <a href="#"><i class='fab fa-instagram' style='font-size:24px'></i> </a>
  <a href="#"> <i class='fab fa-facebook' style='font-size:24px'></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class='fab fa-twitter' style='font-size:24px'></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class='fab fa-linkedin' style='font-size:24px'></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class='fab fa-pinterest' style='font-size:24px'></i></a> 

  </div>

  <div class="menu">  

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/wp/">
        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/cropped-logo-1.png">         </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
        <ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="navbar-nav">
            <li id="menu-item-10" class="nav-item active"><a title="INICIO" class=" nav-link" href="#">INICIO</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-12" class="nav-item"><a title="NOSOTROS" class=" nav-link" href="#">NOSOTROS</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19  nav-item"><a title="BLOG" class=" nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-20  nav-item"><a title="CONTACTO" class=" nav-link" href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks, but I know about font awesome, I want to know how I can put it above of the navbar items

Answer (score -1):

Here's your answer. I can tell you're using WordPress from your code.

1) Install the Better Font Awesome plugin and activate it - https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-font-awesome/

2) Add the following code:
**Note:** *aria-labels* in the code below is used by screen readers like VoiceOver on a Mac (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5R-6WvAihms for a demo) so it's good to include this code. A screen reader (software on a computer, cell phone, or tablet) will say something like "Facebook link" and "WhatsApp link" and then people with disabilties (i.e. blind people) can know it's a link to click on.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" aria-label="Facebook">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
</a>
<a href="https://www.whatsapp.com/" target="_blank" aria-label="WhatsApp">
    <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
etc.
```

3) Do searches for more Font Awesome icon code at https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery